# Root shell is not helping in recovering access to administrator account whose password I have lost

Tags: grub2, login, password

I lost administrative password.

**I have tried** - I know the regular method by which I go to GRUB menu and go to root (drop to root shell prompt) and set password there. It is well described - [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password). To be more specific I am aware about [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/189148) method and have set the password many times when I have lost it before.

**My problem** - now my problem is that this method is not working. When I drop down to root shell it asks for **root password again** without which it does not progress. I do not have this password! What is the alternative then??

Comment: Use a live USB: http://askubuntu.com/a/435347/158442

Comment: is there no any other way out??

Comment: one more thing: @muru - have negatively marked this question? if yes, may I know the reason?

Comment: What's wrong with using a live USB?

Comment: I haven't yet, but if you want, I'll downvote. :P

Comment: @hg8 : sorry but I have already checked the answers for the question which you have mentioned. All most all of them are similar and only one answer which asks me to use live cd is applicable to me. I am looking for answer which does not ask me to use live cd.

Comment: Fine I have removed the possible duplicate ;)

Comment: @muru - :D ... no no... please do not down vote! the only problem with USB is that I do not have one! fine. I will try to solve this "hardware" problem instead of looking for software solution and spending my time. –

Comment: This question does not have an answer here "How do I reset a lost administrative password?" 
I do not understand what is going on. I mention in my question that the said question does not answer my question still why do I see this possible answer link always????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can access the root partition from another system, e.g. a live CD, you can as `root` from there edit `/etc/shadow`; first you have to `chmod u+w shadow`. Find the entry for `root`, it's probably the first one and looks something like this:

```
root:$6$asdG0[..etc...]ae/:15666:0:99999:7:::
```

Erase everything between the first two colons so you end up with:

```
root::15666:0:99999:7:::
```

Then `chmod u-w shadow`. You can now reboot the system and `root` will have no password. You can just type `root` at the login prompt and it won't ask for one. You can then use `passwd` to set one.

Edit 1

Boot to the Live media. Open a terminal. Find out the device name for your primary disk. `sudo fdisk-l` will list all partitions.Like /dev/sda1
Mount this somewhere so we can use it:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Then change directory

```
sudo cd /mnt/etc
```

change privilage

```
sudo chmod u+w shadow
```

edit file like I write

from

```
root:$6$asdG0[..etc...]ae/:15666:0:99999:7:::
```

to

```
root::15666:0:99999:7:::
```

then

```
u-w shadow
```

Reboot

Comment: sorry, I have not understood this part - "you can as root from there edit /etc/shadow;" in your answer.

Comment: **Don't!** change the permissions of `shadow`. Use `vipw -s` instead.

Comment: I edit my answer

Comment: Let us hope @blade19899 does not see this >:-D