# Remove main user password without loosing ability to sudo

Tags: password, user-management

I noticed that after I removed my main user's password that I can't sudo or install new programs because it asks for a password. Ideally I want it to ask for a password to sudo but not to log in or come back from screensaver.
Is this at all possible?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: You can set the system not to require password on boot or resume. You don't remove password for that.

Comment: 1. How do I do that?
2. Does this also work for coming out of screen saver?
If so, post this as an answer.

Comment: System Settings -> Users and groups. That's for login. For screensaver it may be in Power settings depending on DE.

Comment: I don't have these options or you are not being specific enough. I updated the question with the version I am using. Hope it helps :D

Comment: Click the down arrow at the top right of your screen, click your user name -> account settings -> Enable Automatic login

Comment: That's done and it's logging in automatically, but not when returning from screensaver. I would also be interested in actually removing the password without loosing the ability to use the Ubuntu Software app

Comment: You can disable asking a password in a screensaver. You can't totally remove a password.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029696/disable-password-request-from-from-suspend-18-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Terminal, execute
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false`

Then, Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock -> [Move the slider to Off].

The discussion here tell you how to set a new root password if you've lost it: [Root shell is not helping in recovering access to administrator account whose password I have lost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677910/root-shell-is-not-helping-in-recovering-access-to-administrator-account-whose-pa)

Comment: So I guess there is no way to do what I asked... I guess this kind of solves my problem...